# Delegate protocol functions not triggered for UITextView

Tags: swift, delegates, uitextviewdelegate

I have this swift file where I'm trying to create a custom class to handle placeholders for multiple text views on one page. I prefer a separate class because I think its cleaner to handle multiple views. Problem is, the functions *textViewDidEndEditing* and *textViewDidBeginEditing* are not being called when those events occur.

I've had it successfully work by setting the PostPage to the delegate, but I don't see how I could do that with multiple UITextViews.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class PostPage: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var eventDescription: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var eventTitle: UITextView!

    var placeholderShowing = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Add a placeholder for the text
        let ph_descr = PlaceHolderHandler(placeholderText: "Description", textBox: eventDescription)
        eventDescription.delegate = ph_descr

        let ph_title = PlaceHolderHandler(placeholderText: "Title", textBox: eventTitle)
        eventTitle.delegate = ph_title
    }

}

 class PlaceHolderHandler: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {

    var placeholderShowing = true
    var placeholderText = ""

    required init(placeholderText: String, textBox: UITextView) {
        super.init()
        self.placeholderText = placeholderText
        textBox.text = placeholderText
        textBox.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    }


    // MARK:- UITextViewDelegates

    public func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if self.placeholderShowing {
            textView.text = ""
            textView.textColor = UIColor.black
            self.placeholderShowing = false
        }

    }

    public func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView.text == "" {
            textView.text = "Description"
            textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
            self.placeholderShowing = true
        }
    }
 }
```

When I select either of the UITextViews, I'd like the corresponding function to be called, and have the text adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to retain `phDescr` and `phTitle` as in your code they are local variables so get de-allocated end of `viewDidLoad`

```
import UIKit

class PostPage: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var eventDescription: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var eventTitle: UITextView!

    var placeholderShowing = true

    var phDescr, phTitle:PlaceHolderHandler!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Add a placeholder for the text
        phDescr = PlaceHolderHandler(placeholderText: "Description", textBox: eventDescription)
        eventDescription.delegate = phDescr

        phTitle = PlaceHolderHandler(placeholderText: "Title", textBox: eventTitle)
        eventTitle.delegate = phTitle
    }

}
```

also use camelCase to name variables

> I've had it successfully work by setting the PostPage to the delegate, but I don't see how I could do that with multiple UITextView

Off course you can set the delegate for both to `PostPage` and to know which 1 is intact use

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
   if textView == eventDescription {
   }
   else {  // eventTitle
   }
}
```